# How to count the number of collisions with collidesWith() in JavaME?

Tags: java, java-me, collision

I'm developing a game with JavaME and I need to count the number of collisions in my game.
I'm using the `collidesWith()` method, and I'm doing something like this:

```
private void checkCollision() 
{   
    if (spBoy.collidesWith(spBall, true)) {
            this.collides++;
            if (this.collides == 3) {
                //here I will show a Game Over image.
            }                
    }          
}
```

As you can see, if the number of collisions is 3, the game is over, but I can't count the number of collisions, because when I increment `this.collides`, automatically I have 3 collisions in one time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're calling `checkCollision()` inside your main loop. This means it gets called 30-60 times per second.
If the two sprites doesn't move at all during that second, there will be 30-60 collisions - because it's true in each cycle.
What you wanna do is add a timer where your `spBoy` sprite can't be hurt.

```
int safeTimer = 0;
int timeSinceLastLoop; // Add this calculation to your loop

private void checkCollision() {
 safeTimer-= timeSinceLastLoop;
 if (spBoy.collidesWith(spBall, true) && safeTimer<=0) {
  this.collides++;
  safeTimer=3000; // Wait 3 seconds till vulnerability
  if (this.collides == 3) {
   //here I will show a Game Over image.
  }                
 }          
}
```